# An iOS SIP client that supports CallKit?

Tags: ios, voip

I'm looking for an SIP client for iOS that supports [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit) - a new iOS 10 API that allows VoIP apps to blend into the OS and behave like the native Phone app (answer directly from the lockscreen, etc). License doesn't matter and I am happy to put good money into it if the app is worth the price.

My current app Bria (which is great if we ignore this issue) [doesn't look very enthusiastic about supporting this](https://support.counterpath.com/topic/bria-in-ios-10-voip-api) so I am looking for an alternative.

Comment: I've heard that SessionTalk intend to have CallKit available with their iOS SIP Client by early October. http://sessiontalk.co.uk

Comment: I'm afraid a cloud-based solution is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: No there is a standalone iOS SIP Client see here--> http://sessiontalk.co.uk/iphone-sip-voip-phone-dialer/

Comment: @acrobits Softphone already supports #CallKit https://twitter.com/acrobits/status/779227816785313792